# No matching overloaded function found - Threads

Tags: c++, multithreading

For the code snippet below, I keep getting the invoke error C6272. I have tried multiple things - passing using ref, without it and even testing as a simple thread. For context, the member function is a function that multiplies two sparse matrices and adds them to a linked list. Without using threads, the function works fine but threads returns an error.

```
mutex m;
vector<thread> a;
for (int q = 0; q < rhs.num_columns_; q++) { 
    a.push_back(thread(&SparseMatrix::mul_node, rhs_rows, lhs_rows, q, ref(newMatrix), ref(m)));
}
for (thread& t : a) {
    t.join();
}
```

Declaration of the mul_node function

```
void SparseMatrix::mul_node(vector<vector<int>> rhs, vector<vector<int>> lhs, int pos_rhs, row_node* &newMatrix, mutex &m) const`
```

I have not been able to find a solution yet for the problem above, please let me know what exactly is causing the issue and how I can fix it? Thank you

Comment: Is `SparseMatrix::mul_node` a `static` member function?

Comment: I believe not. It is not static @TedLyngmo

Comment: Then, you need to pass the instance you want to run the function on to the `thread` constructor too. Added an answer to show where.

Comment: Please include not only the error code, but the description of the error code as well. Also which compiler are you using? This information will help understanding the error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the member function is not `static` you need to pass a pointer to the *instance* of the `SparseMatrix` on to the `std::thread` constructor too.

Simplified example:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>

struct foo {
    ~foo() {
        if(th.joinable()) th.join();
    }

    void run() {
        th = std::thread(&foo::thread_func, this, 10, 20);
        //                                  ^^^^
    }

    void thread_func(int a, int b) {
        std::cout << "doing the stuff " << a << ' ' << b << '\n';
    }

    std::thread th;
};

int main() {
    foo f;
    f.run();
}
```

Here `10` and `20` are passed as parameters to `this->thread_func`.

Comment: So I just need to add this to it after I add the member function first?
EDIT: THIS WORKED, thanks so much!

Comment: @abdullahahmad Yes, first the member function, the pointer to instance and then the arguments to the function. EDIT: You're welcome! :-)